# How to return 403 instead of redirect to access denied when AuthorizeFilter fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

In Startup.ConfigureServices() I configure authorization filter like this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(myAuthorizationPolicy));
})
```

and I use either cookie authentication or AAD authentication based on config:

```
if (useCookieAuth)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie();
}
else
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAd", options));
}
```

Now, when I visit a page and `myAuthorizationPolicy` fails, I'm redirected to "Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2F", but I want to return 403 instead.

Answer (score 23):

It seems that you have to override the OnRedirectToAccessDenied

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => {
        options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context => {
             context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
             return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, but what about AAD authentication?

Comment: More likely you have to create you own AddAzureAD() as it seems to be not configurable yet...

Comment: Something like public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<azureadoptions> configureOptions)
{
builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<iconfigureoptions<openidconnectoptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
builder.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = RedirectToIdentityProvider
};
});
return builder;
}

Comment: That works nice!! Its missing the return Task.CompletedTask

Comment: This is not working on server-side when I use Blazor WebAssembly Solution

Comment: @Simon I have not tested it with Blazor WebAssembly... it might be a better option to ask a separate question if there is any specific besides this one

Comment: @BorisSokolov: Yes of course. I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191785/how-can-i-return-403-forbidden-instead-redirect-in-blazor-web-assembly-app

Answer (score 5):

For those people out there (*cough* me) who use Azure AD and are making use of in their `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);
```

The solution is the following addition:

```
        services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = new Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task>(context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
                return context.Response.CompleteAsync();
            });
        });
```

With this, ASP.NET will no longer redirect to `AccessDenied` but will return a `403` instead.

More details can be found here: https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2020/12/21/how-to-make-azure-ad-403/ (but all you really need is in this answer I hope)

Comment: I've tried this, but for some reason it's not working (a breakpoint within the function is not being triggered). I still get redirected to ADB2C login page.  Any clue as to what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently and was able to find instructions related to how to override the default cookie behavior within AzureADB2C at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-the-underlying-openidconnectoptionsjwtbearercookie-options

Here is an example of implementing that override to return a simple 403 instead of redirecting:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADB2C();

services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions> (AzureADB2CDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
{
    // Stop AzureADB2C from redirecting 403's, which it does by default.  We just want to return the 403.
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = new Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task>(context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
        return context.Response.CompleteAsync();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AuthorizeOrForbidAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
        }

    }
}
```

Try above filter.

Comment: Where should I use this?

Comment: options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(myAuthorizationPolicy));  Can you send myAuthorizationPolicy method? I have to see this method first.

Comment: If you doesn't have any code in myAuthorizationPolicy method, then please create a class like above code. and remove your code options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(myAuthorizationPolicy)); <br> . Then add this line options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeOrForbidAttribute());

Answer (score 0):

You coudl create a custom `Authorization Filter` combined with your policy.

```
public class MyAuthorizeFilter: IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public MyAuthorizeFilter(string policy)
    {
        Policy = policy;
    }

    public string Policy { get; set; }
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        var authZService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
        var accessable = await authZService.AuthorizeAsync(user, null, this.Policy);
        if (!accessable.Succeeded)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        }

    }
}
```

and now you can use the authorization filter to intercept request :

```
[MyAuthorizeFilter("MyPolicy")]
public IActionResult Index()
```

or globally:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeFilter("MyPolicy"));              
        });
```

Of course , we need to register the policy firstly .

```
services.AddAuthorization(o => {
            o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", pb => {
                pb.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                //...
            });
        });
```