# How can I return 403 Forbidden instead redirect in Blazor Web Assembly app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We have an Blazor WebAssembly-App which works with an ASP.NET Core API-Controller (V3.1). The Authentication Cookie which works well with `[Authorize]` attribute in our Api-Controller:

```
namespace BlazorWebAssemblyApp.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientsController : ControllerBase
    {          
        private const string AuthSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        [HttpGet("search")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]
        public ActionResult<List<Shared.Client>> Search(Shared.Client.SearchProperty pProperty, string pText)
        {
            // [...]
        }
    }
}
```

We are using the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461127/how-to-return-403-instead-of-redirect-to-access-denied-when-authorizefilter-fail) to return an HTTP-Status Code `403 Forbidden` instead routing to the login page.

```
namespace BlazorWebAssemblyApp.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // [...]

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // [...]
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options => {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context => {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But the Solution is not working. The app still redirects to default path `/Account/Login`:

[image]

How can I return the http-status code 403 Forbidden instead redirect in Blazor Web Assembly app?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'returning 403', what do you expect the user to see?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: When I get an http-status code 403 then I can handle it by an suiteable errormessage and redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: Is there any chance to see how does your blazor web-client handling cookies, I am more fun of cookies then JWT barrier, But I do not know how to save cookie in my webassambly http client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `OnRedirectToLogin` yet

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // or 403 if you want
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

Comment: I already added this codeblock. Please look into my question.

Comment: @Simon, you have added `OnRedirectToAccessDenied`. Just add `OnRedirectToLogin` below

Comment: @Simon, I have an AspNet.Core Blazor WebAssembly project working with 401 for non-authenticated requests and 403 for non-authorized

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using cookie authentication scheme please use a JWT bearer authentication scheme, cookie authentication scheme will always redirect the user to default login page.
Please modify your code as below:-

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "";
                options.Audience = "";
            });
```

Please pass the appropriate **authority** and **audience**.                                         With above code the server has now been configured to authenticate and authorize the request by inspecting the access token and will now return a 401 unauthorized if the either token is not supplied or incorrect token is passed.

Comment: At the api level please dont decorate the  authorize attribute with any authentication scheme it should pick up the auth scheme from the configured service.

Comment: "cookie authentication scheme will always redirect the user to default login page" it is not true, see my answer below

Comment: @3per- Agreed brother..I apologize.. what i meant the authentication scheme should be JWT bearer instead of cookie authentication since the requirement  is that  the api call if its not authenticated should fail with 401 instead of getting redirected to login page.

Comment: @simon-It would be really helpful if you can shed some light so as to whether you are protecting your api with an access token or if the requirement is that if the user is not authenticated then the request should fail with a 401?